# C++ operator overloading weird type conversion

Tags: c++, xcode, llvm

I have simple c++ class vector and it has parameter constructor as follow:

```
Vector::Vector(int size){
   ...
}
```

Based on this implementation following lines are valid:

```
Vector v(1);
Vector v2(94);
```

My question is I was testing my code and I came across this was also valid:

```
Vector v = 1;
```

which called parameter constructor somehow. I also overloaded operator = but in this case it was never called. Is this normal behavior in c++? How does a compiler treat above assignment as `Vector v(1)`? I'm doing this in Xcode 5.0 (LLVM compiler)

Comment: One's direct initialization and one's copy-initialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not overloaded operator `=`, it's copy-initialization. If you want prevent such construction of vector, then you can use `explicit` constructor.

```
explicit Vector(int);
```

now

```
Vector v = 1;
```

is incorrect.

Comment: So is this normal behavior if a class has parameter constructor which takes int?

Comment: @REALFREE yes, it's expected behavior, see `explicit` keyword for more info

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to 'Automatic Type Conversion' that compiler supports quietly. That's why it works with no copy constructor.

Bruce Eckel tells in his book "Thinking in C++":

> *The default constructor, copy-constructor, operator= and destructor can be synthesized automatically by compiler.*

Comment: This happens due to implicit call of the constructor `Vector::Vector(int size){...}` that is already defined

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Here, built-in data type is being used with assignment operator. That's why compiler can't overload *operator=*.

Comment: "The default constructor, copy-constructor, operator= and destructor can be synthesized" - Mr Eckel's statement seems to describe how default constructors et al can be automatically created/synthesized by the compiler to copy bases and members, or call base/member destructors.  It's not relevant to the question, in which it's a user-defined constructor that's invoked.

Answer (score -1):

The following , x2 would call copy constructor in x2 = x1 ;

```
ClassX  x1() ;
ClassX  x2 =  x1 ;
```

The following , x4 would call copy assignment in x4 = x3 ;

```
ClassX  x3() ;
ClassX  x4() ;
x4 = x3 ;
```

If ClassX has explicit in copy construtor , then

```
ClassX x5(x1) ;  //this will compiled ok 
ClassX x5 = x1 ; //This will fail while compiled
```

Comment: "ClassX  x1();" - this declares a function `x1` that takes no arguments and returns an object of type `ClassX`.  Same for `x3`/`x4`.